Don't domain events violate "aggregate = transactional boundary"?
The conventional implementation of "domain events" in DDD as formulated in lots of articles (such as this one, this one, and this one), seems as though it's at odds with DDD. Because the very thing it apparently accomplishes is to enable making cross-aggregate changes synchronously and then persisting them as part of the same database transaction.
But is this sound, according to DDD principles, given that an aggregate is supposed to be the transaction boundary?
For example, to quote the first article I linked to:

This pattern isn’t always applicable.  If I need to do something like send an email, notify a web service or any other potentially blocking tasks, I should revert back to normal asynchronous messaging.  But for synchronous messaging across disconnected aggregates, domain events are a great way to ensure aggregate root consistency across the entire model.  The alternative would be transaction script design, where consistency is enforced not by the domain model but by some other (non-intuitive) layer.

(emphasis mine)
Corect me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the notion of "synchronous messaging across disconnected aggregates", and by extension persisting changes to them in a single transaction, is just in opposition to the idea of an aggregate being a consistency boundary, which is fundamental to DDD, as far I understand. Yet, it looks like this variation of the "domain events" idea is pretty popular in DDD-adjacent spaces; and nobody seems to have noticed this apparent contradiction — or at least I couldn't find anything on the web that explicitly acknowledged it.
What am I missing here? Is this actually a sound thing to do, or are people misguided?

Reminder: aggregates aren't real - they aren't a chapter 5 this is how we model a business pattern, they are a chapter 6 this is how we manage life cycles because we are tracking the business with computers pattern.

But is this sound, according to DDD principles, given that an aggregate is supposed to be a transaction boundary?

That's not quite the original phrasing.  Aggregates, in the Evans pattern book, are "clusters of associated objects that we treat as a unit for the purpose of data changes".  That doesn't say "one unit per transaction", it says that all of the unit participates in the transaction.
Changing more than one aggregate in a single transaction is fine, so long as you understood early enough in the design of the system that this was a desirable property.
It's not "free", of course - locking two things has more complicated failure modes than locking one thing.  If you want to be robust / resilient in the face of those kinds of failures, then that's going to remove some of the degrees of freedom you would otherwise have in designing the system.

Thanks for the answer. Would it be true to say you've changed your mind since this answer though? There, you seemed to confidently disapprove of the idea of changing multiple aggregates in one transaction — confusing.

Sometimes, eventual consistency just isn't acceptable?
So, what to do?
Given unlimited time and budget you might go back to the drawing board and try to refactor your domain to avoid the requirement for immediate consistency across multiple aggregates.  But sometimes it's just more practical and realistic to update multiple aggregates within a single transaction boundary, whilst acknowledging that you're adding some tight coupling.  It's not pure but it's pragmatic.
You could use orchestration in a Domain Service to manage updates across multiple aggregates or use collaboration via Domain Events.  I prefer collaboration as I feel it aligns better with the Single Responsibility Principle as there are then a separate command handler (to update the primary aggregate) and a domain event handler (to perform side-effect updates in other aggregates).  It also supports the Open/Closed principal as I can add additional Domain Event Handlers if I want additional side effects without changing existing code.
In conclusion, I would agree with your analysis but balance that purist view with the adage "perfection is the enemy of progress".  Sometimes, you've just got to crack on with the job, so I'd be comfortable to use these 'tools', acknowledge that I'm doing it, document it thoroughly, maybe add it to a tech-debt log for later consideration, and move on.
